# change Configuration for google chart tools

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I was trying to use piechart provided by google chart tools. Their documentation specifies a set of configuration options

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options

But I don't know how or where to specify them within the sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration is done using the options variable that is given in the sample code.
To change the background color, I replaced this

```
  var options = {'title':'Some Title',
                 'width':400,
                 'height':300};
```

by this

```
  var options = {'title':'Some Title',
                 'width':400,
                 'height':300, 'backgroundColor':'#EEF4EE'};
```